# Laravel conditional relationship - hasOne specified by model's type

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-nova

I have a model **Chapter** which have field **type** than can be (article, video, quiz). To solve my problem I have to create a new model **Quiz** which will have relationship oneToOne with Chapter model whether type of Chapter == "quiz".

I've tried something like this and it works when type == "quiz" only. I guess I'll have to return other relations for other types for it to work, but I don't have nothing to return so I wanted to leave it empty for other types.

```
public function quizQuestions(){
        if($this->chapter_type == "QUIZ"){
            return $this->hasMany(QuizQuestion::class);
        }
    }
```

The point is, I want to somehow return empty relation for other types. I'm building an app in Laravel Nova and I wanted to hide Quiz table if a chapter is not type of "quiz" but it can't be done this way.

```
NovaDependencyContainer::make([
   HasMany::make('QuizQuestions'),
])->dependsOn('chapter_type' , \App\Models\Chapter::QUIZ),
```

I might have missed something in documentation or I just don't understand something so thanks in advance for you help and advices!

Comment: You are probably looking for a [polymorphic relation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations).

Comment: I don't think so, in my case QuizQuestion should be linked only to Chapter model so I don't think it will solve the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning null otherwise:

```
public function quizQuestions(){
        if($this->chapter_type == "QUIZ"){
            return $this->hasMany(QuizQuestion::class);
        }
       return $this->hasMany(QuizQuestion::class)->where('id', -1);
    }
```

Comment: This provides me an error "Call to a member function tap() on null" and does not solve it, I guess you can't return relation as a null

Comment: yes your are right, isnce it is a hasmany relation ship, it should return empty relationship not null. See my updated answer above.

Comment: Now it gets me to "Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::getQuery does not exist."

Comment: hmm then it is not the most elegant but you can try returning  the sam realtionship, but wiht a condition, to make sure it doesnt find any (see updated answer)

Comment: Well now it says that there's no column in db from where clausule, anyway I guess Laravel Nova will have to display empty array when relation is empty so I think I can't solve this that way, anyway thanks for your help!

Comment: oh I am sorry I couldnt help, lets try out one last thing, where (id, -1) :)

Comment: Well, didn't work neither, thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

**I advise you to re-think your Model, but not too many edits.**

I have done things like you want in this manner:

> return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Main\QuizQuestion','id','id')->where('chapter_type', '=', 1);

then ->where('chapter_type', '=', 2);

Works like a charm!!

Comment: The problem is, it should return relation only when chapter_type == 'quiz' otherwise it should return something like null, but null is not working

Answer (score 0):

After couple of sleepless nights and days full of crying I finally came up with a solution:

```
public function fieldsForDetail(Request $request)
{
    if ($this->model()->chapter_type == "QUIZ") {
        return [
            $this->chapterCredentials(),

            HasMany::make('QuizQuestions'),
        ];
    }

    return [
        $this->chapterCredentials(),
    ];
}

public function chapterCredentials()
{
    return $this->merge([
        Text::make('Chapter Name', 'chapter_name')
                ->sortable()
                ->rules('required', 'max:100'),

        TextArea::make('Chapter Description', 'chapter_description'),

        Select::make('Chapter Type', 'chapter_type')->options([
            \App\Models\Chapter::ARTICLE => 'Article',
            \App\Models\Chapter::VIDEO => 'Video',
            \App\Models\Chapter::QUIZ => 'Quiz',
        ])->rules('required'),

        BelongsTo::make('Course', 'Course')->searchable(),
    ]);
}
```

Now in a display view it shows linked model QuizQuestion only when type of the model equals "QUIZ"